# Creating a Firebase development environment?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

What's the best way to work with multiple environments/projects on firebase?

I can switch between firebase projects using the the CLI.

I see [here how to add environment variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env) to a firebase project and access them through `firebase-functions`'s `.config()` method.

Is there a way to do something similar on the client-side when using firebase hosting.

For example: I'm using Algolia to run searches. I have firebase-functions to keep the indexes up to date, and run the searches from the client. Both functions and the hosted content need to point to the right Algolia project depending on the environment. I'd like to tie both configs to the same switch; `firebase use staging` vs `firebase use production`, for example. What's the best way to go about that?